# How to populate data using ref with double connection in Nestjs Mongodb

Tags: nestjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rZxd.png) my app.module.ts and my user.schema.ts file is this [enter image description `here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDMdH.png) and my book.schema.ts is this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w357.png) and how to populate data from book.schema.ts in user.schema.ts and my user.service.ts is this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3ciJ.png) and i am trying to populate bookId and i got error schema hasn't registered and i got this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhuiS.png) how to solve please Help me i am a beginners

i stuck from 20 days please help me

Comment: there is absolutely no reason why anyone has to follow links to pictures of text ... please add the code, and errors, to your question as text, not pictures, not links ... format it as code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.